# AttributeError: module 'huggingface_hub.constants' has no attribute 'HF_HUB_CACHE'

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-hub

I got this error after running:

```py
import os 
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn  
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig,AutoModelForCausalLM
```

I tried installing deferent versions of `huggingface_hub`, `transformers`, `dataset` and `accelerate` but the issue persists.

Comment: Which version of `transformers` and `huggingface-hub` library are you using?

Comment: I hit the same error. I'm using transformers installed via conda with ` 4.38.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0 `

Comment: My `huggingface-hub` version is `0.17.3`

Comment: `pip install --upgrade huggingface_hub` did the trick :)